# How to build a method to iterate through WebElements and return the one that is displayed using Selenium & Java?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects, page-factory

So, the page is filled with a lot of similar properties like these two elements below.
Examples:

```
<button id="exibe_codigo_de_barras_210888-1" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-ver-codigo-barras-colapse" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%" class="styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 gMrMBo" style="" xpath="1">VER CÓDIGO DE BARRAS <span class="sc-1o2smz3-2 dAGdGd styled__Arrow-tuh5ii-0 iYDeiw"><svg width="12px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 12 8" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><polygon id="chevron" points="7.41 8 12 12.9446694 16.59 8 18 9.52226721 12 16 6 9.52226721"></polygon></defs><g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Interface/Seta-expandir" transform="translate(-6.000000, -8.000000)"><mask id="mask-2" fill="white"><use xlink:href="#chevron"></use></mask><use id="Seta-expandir" fill="#D82482" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#chevron"></use></g></g></svg></span></button>
```

---

```
<button id="exibe_codigo_de_barras_210888-2" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-ver-codigo-barras-colapse" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%" class="styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 gMrMBo" style="" xpath="1">VER CÓDIGO DE BARRAS <span class="sc-1o2smz3-2 dAGdGd styled__Arrow-tuh5ii-0 iYDeiw"><svg width="12px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 12 8" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><polygon id="chevron" points="7.41 8 12 12.9446694 16.59 8 18 9.52226721 12 16 6 9.52226721"></polygon></defs><g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Interface/Seta-expandir" transform="translate(-6.000000, -8.000000)"><mask id="mask-2" fill="white"><use xlink:href="#chevron"></use></mask><use id="Seta-expandir" fill="#D82482" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#chevron"></use></g></g></svg></span></button>
```

I'm using PageObject and PageFactory to get the elements and putting them in an array like this:

```
@FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "[data-context=minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-ver-codigo-barras-colapse]"))
public List<WebElement> btnVerCodigoDeBarras;
```

The problem is this: I need to click one of these similar buttons, without using index (**because it turned out to be a hell to maintain**). I thought of a method that I could collect all the webElements of a list and return the single one that is displayed on the screen (I'm open to new ideas), so here are the two methods I tried without success:

```
public static WebElement WaitForElementVisibleInArray(List<WebElement> elements) {
    boolean arrayNotEmpty = elements.size() > 0;
    if (arrayNotEmpty) {
        for (Iterator<WebElement> i = elements.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            WebElement element = i.next();
            if (element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed()) {
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

```
public static WebElement WaitForElementVisibleInArray(List<WebElement> elements) {
    boolean arrayNotEmpty = elements.size() > 0;        
    if (arrayNotEmpty) {            
        Iterator<WebElement> it = elements.iterator();
        WebElement element;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            element = it.next();
            if (element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed()) {
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've searched a lot and couldn't manage to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Edit:

As requested, here's below two examples of the div parent that contains several divs children:
First div:

```html
<div class="sc-1o2smz3-8 bdzhlP styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 SpKwt"><div><button id="envia_codigo_de_barras_210888-1" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-enviar" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M20 4H4c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L2 18c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H4V8l8 5 8-5v10zm-8-7L4 6h16l-8 5z"></path></svg> Enviar</button><div class="modal styled__Modal-a94357-0 fQRtzL"><aside class="overlay styled__Overlay-gtv01n-0 joIHPo"></aside><div radius="4" display="flex" direction="column" width="100%" height="auto" cursor="initial" order="0" class="Modal__Container-sc-13j9751-1 cbeGrw Container__ContainerStyle-sc-1iqy2ia-0 dVRtOm" style="max-width: 500px; display: flex; flex: 1 1 0%;"><button class="fechar styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30"><path fill="#9B9B9B" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.106 15.09L8.227 19.85l1.625 2.035 5.119-4.976 5.099 4.976 1.882-1.83-5.109-4.966 5.109-4.967-1.882-1.83-5.1 4.976-5.118-4.976-1.625 2.035 4.879 4.762zM15 30C6.716 30 0 23.284 0 15 0 6.716 6.716 0 15 0c8.284 0 15 6.716 15 15 0 8.284-6.716 15-15 15z"></path></svg></button><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras" style="width: 100%;"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 bWdzYK"><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI"><h2 class="sc-1h9tg9u-1 ieQsBc Title__TitleStyle-sc-5b4olk-0 gZiyVB" font-weight="Regular" width="100%">Enviar código de barras</h2></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 cXZsiu"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cEyrnf"><label class="progress-bar styled__Radio-sc-13c6bcq-0 jIgdvS" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-radio_forma-envio" id="envio_email"><input type="checkbox" checked=""><span></span><p font-size="18px" type="p" align="left" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-weight="Regular" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" lineheight="1em" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial" class="Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 gTxJFk">&nbsp;E-mail</p></label></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 fKsxZO"></div><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cEyrnf"><label class="progress-bar styled__Radio-sc-13c6bcq-0 jIgdvS" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-radio_forma-envio" id="envio_sms"><input type="checkbox"><span></span><p font-size="18px" type="p" align="left" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-weight="Regular" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" lineheight="1em" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial" class="Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 gTxJFk">&nbsp;SMS pra Celular Oi</p></label></div><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cEyrnf"></div></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cKjXbt"><fieldset class="styledFieldset-sc-1r2we57-0 jBoAvV"><input class="sc-1h9tg9u-0 dFDlQp styledInput__Input-sc-1apvofq-0 bkjwCX" id="informe_email" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-text_email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" maxlength="50" value=""><div class="sc-1h9tg9u-0 dFDlQp styledMessage-d8kpbw-0 gAaQEw"></div></fieldset></div></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 kRKEGz"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cKjXbt"><button disabled="" id="submit_envio" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-submit" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%" class="styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 crrbD">ENVIAR</button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><button data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-copiar" id="copia_codigo_de_barras_210888-1" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M16 1H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14h2V3h12V1zm-1 4l6 6v10c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2H7.99C6.89 23 6 22.1 6 21l.01-14c0-1.1.89-2 1.99-2h7zm-1 7h5.5L14 6.5V12z"></path></svg> Copiar código</button><button data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-baixar-pdf" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M14 2H6c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L4 20c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2H18c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V8l-6-6zm2 16H8v-2h8v2zm0-4H8v-2h8v2zm-3-5V3.5L18.5 9H13z"></path></svg> Baixar PDF</button><button id="imprime_fatura_210888-1" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-imprimir" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 8H5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3v6h4v4h12v-4h4v-6c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm-3 11H8v-5h8v5zm3-7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1 1 .45 1 1-.45 1-1 1zm-1-9H6v4h12V3z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path></svg> Imprimir</button></div>
```

And the second div:

```html
<div class="sc-1o2smz3-0 dzkPUw styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI" data-context="minhas-contas_conta"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cTsLBT" width="100%"><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 bTDNmX"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cEyrnf"><div class="no-wrap styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 hfVmIP"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 hAdyfM"><label class="progress-bar styled__Radio-sc-13c6bcq-0 kXqgpo" id="seleciona_fatura_210888-2"><input type="checkbox"><span></span></label></div><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 lnnClR"><div class="sc-1o2smz3-8 bdzhlP styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 fpsrZI"><h3 font-family="SimplonMedium" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_valor" font-weight="Regular" width="100%" class="Title__TitleStyle-sc-5b4olk-0 kCdfIG">R$ &nbsp;99,88&nbsp;</h3></div><p font-size="14px" lineheight="1.5em" type="p" align="left" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-weight="Regular" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial" class="Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 bcIQEp">Vencimento: 11/03/2018</p><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_status"><div font-size="14" width="auto" class="Alert__StyledAlert-huwm74-0 cOBlGy"><div></div><div>Vencida há <strong data-context="minhas-contas_conta_tempo-vencimento">368 dias</strong></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 fKsxZO"></div><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 kGpLSX"><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 lnnClR"><button id="baixa_pdf_210888-2" data-context="minhas-contas_produto_conta_btn-ver-boleto" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%" class="styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK">Baixar conta em PDF</button></div></div></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI"></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 fKsxZO"></div><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 jtUyYJ"><button id="exibe_codigo_de_barras_210888-2" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-ver-codigo-barras" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%" class="styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 gMrMBo">VER CÓDIGO DE BARRAS <span class="sc-1o2smz3-2 dAGdGd styled__Arrow-tuh5ii-0 dYwLxl"><svg width="12px" height="8px" viewBox="0 0 12 8" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><polygon id="chevron" points="7.41 8 12 12.9446694 16.59 8 18 9.52226721 12 16 6 9.52226721"></polygon></defs><g id="Symbols" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Interface/Seta-expandir" transform="translate(-6.000000, -8.000000)"><mask id="mask-2" fill="white"><use xlink:href="#chevron"></use></mask><use id="Seta-expandir" fill="#D82482" fill-rule="nonzero" xlink:href="#chevron"></use></g></g></svg></span></button></div></div><div height="260" class="sc-1o2smz3-6 dJMXeH Collapsible__CollapsibleContainer-sc-12167wd-0 gksWIz" width="100%" open=""><div class="sc-1o2smz3-7 EuVAO"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 feSHva"><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 bVFhjc"><svg width="648px" height="80px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 648 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="transform: translate(0,0)"><rect x="0" y="0" width="648" height="80" style="fill:#ffffff;"></rect><g transform="translate(0, 0)" style="fill:#000000;"><rect x="0" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="3.2000000000000006" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="6.4" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="12.8" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="16" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="22.400000000000002" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="28.8" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="35.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="38.400000000000006" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="44.8" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="54.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="60.800000000000004" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="64.00000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="67.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="70.4" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="80.00000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="89.60000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="92.80000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="96.00000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="99.2" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="108.80000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="118.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="121.60000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="124.80000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="128" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="137.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="147.20000000000002" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="150.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="153.60000000000002" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="160" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="166.4" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="176.00000000000003" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="179.20000000000002" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="185.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="192.00000000000003" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="195.2" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="204.8" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="208" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="214.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="217.60000000000002" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="224" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="233.60000000000002" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="236.8" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="246.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="249.60000000000002" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="252.8" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="256" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="265.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="272" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="281.59999999999997" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="284.8" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="288" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="294.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="297.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="304" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="310.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="313.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="323.2" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="332.8" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="336" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="342.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="345.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="352" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="361.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="364.8" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="374.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="377.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="380.8" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="387.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="393.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="396.8" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="406.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="409.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="416" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="419.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="425.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="435.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="438.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="441.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="448" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="454.40000000000003" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="464" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="467.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="470.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="473.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="483.2" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="492.8" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="496" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="502.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="505.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="515.2" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="521.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="524.8000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="531.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="537.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="544" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="547.2" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="553.6" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="560" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="563.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="569.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="576.0000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="582.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="585.6" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="588.8000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="598.4000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="608" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="611.2" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="614.4" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="617.6000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="627.2" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="636.8000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect><rect x="640.0000000000001" y="0" width="4.800000000000001" height="80"></rect><rect x="646.4000000000001" y="0" width="1.6" height="80"></rect></g></svg></div><p align="center" font-weight="Bold" lineheight="1.5" type="p" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-size="16" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial" class="Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 iWZvwv">84600000000-6  99880113224-7  51558980900-0  00516100000-4</p></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 kHQmEI"><div class="sc-1o2smz3-9 jjdcZL Alert__StyledAlert-huwm74-0 cOBlGy" font-size="14" width="auto"><div></div><div><p class="sc-1o2smz3-3 kPGwia Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 beCits" type="p" align="left" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-weight="Regular" font-size="16" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" lineheight="1em" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial">Lembre-se que esta conta está cadastrada em Débito Automático.<br>Se realizar o pagamento agora, você deverá entrar em contato com seu banco pra retirar o débito programado.</p></div></div></div><div class="sc-1o2smz3-8 bdzhlP styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 SpKwt"><div><button id="envia_codigo_de_barras_210888-2" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-enviar" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M20 4H4c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L2 18c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h16c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V6c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 14H4V8l8 5 8-5v10zm-8-7L4 6h16l-8 5z"></path></svg> Enviar</button><div class="modal styled__Modal-a94357-0 fQRtzL"><aside class="overlay styled__Overlay-gtv01n-0 joIHPo"></aside><div radius="4" display="flex" direction="column" width="100%" height="auto" cursor="initial" order="0" class="Modal__Container-sc-13j9751-1 cbeGrw Container__ContainerStyle-sc-1iqy2ia-0 dVRtOm" style="max-width: 500px; display: flex; flex: 1 1 0%;"><button class="fechar styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30"><path fill="#9B9B9B" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.106 15.09L8.227 19.85l1.625 2.035 5.119-4.976 5.099 4.976 1.882-1.83-5.109-4.966 5.109-4.967-1.882-1.83-5.1 4.976-5.118-4.976-1.625 2.035 4.879 4.762zM15 30C6.716 30 0 23.284 0 15 0 6.716 6.716 0 15 0c8.284 0 15 6.716 15 15 0 8.284-6.716 15-15 15z"></path></svg></button><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras" style="width: 100%;"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 bWdzYK"><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI"><h2 class="sc-1h9tg9u-1 ieQsBc Title__TitleStyle-sc-5b4olk-0 gZiyVB" font-weight="Regular" width="100%">Enviar código de barras</h2></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 cXZsiu"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cEyrnf"><label class="progress-bar styled__Radio-sc-13c6bcq-0 jIgdvS" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-radio_forma-envio" id="envio_email"><input type="checkbox" checked=""><span></span><p font-size="18px" type="p" align="left" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-weight="Regular" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" lineheight="1em" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial" class="Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 gTxJFk">&nbsp;E-mail</p></label></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 fKsxZO"></div><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cEyrnf"><label class="progress-bar styled__Radio-sc-13c6bcq-0 jIgdvS" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-radio_forma-envio" id="envio_sms"><input type="checkbox"><span></span><p font-size="18px" type="p" align="left" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-weight="Regular" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" lineheight="1em" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial" class="Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 gTxJFk">&nbsp;SMS pra Celular Oi</p></label></div><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cEyrnf"></div></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gPFeBI"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cKjXbt"><fieldset class="styledFieldset-sc-1r2we57-0 jBoAvV"><input class="sc-1h9tg9u-0 dFDlQp styledInput__Input-sc-1apvofq-0 bkjwCX" id="informe_email" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-text_email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" maxlength="50" value=""><div class="sc-1h9tg9u-0 dFDlQp styledMessage-d8kpbw-0 gAaQEw"></div></fieldset></div></div><div class="Row styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 kRKEGz"><div class="col styled__Col-sc-4ph28m-0 cKjXbt"><button disabled="" id="submit_envio" data-context="popup_enviar-codigo-barras_input-submit" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%" class="styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 crrbD">ENVIAR</button></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><button data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-copiar" id="copia_codigo_de_barras_210888-2" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path><path d="M16 1H4c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14h2V3h12V1zm-1 4l6 6v10c0 1.1-.9 2-2 2H7.99C6.89 23 6 22.1 6 21l.01-14c0-1.1.89-2 1.99-2h7zm-1 7h5.5L14 6.5V12z"></path></svg> Copiar código</button><button data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-baixar-pdf" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path><path d="M14 2H6c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L4 20c0 1.1.89 2 1.99 2H18c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V8l-6-6zm2 16H8v-2h8v2zm0-4H8v-2h8v2zm-3-5V3.5L18.5 9H13z"></path></svg> Baixar PDF</button><button id="imprime_fatura_210888-2" data-context="minhas-contas_conta_codigo-barras_btn-imprimir" class="sc-1o2smz3-5 gzODBO styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg fill="#D82482" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 8H5c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3v6h4v4h12v-4h4v-6c0-1.66-1.34-3-3-3zm-3 11H8v-5h8v5zm3-7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1s.45-1 1-1 1 .45 1 1-.45 1-1 1zm-1-9H6v4h12V3z"></path><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path></svg> Imprimir</button></div></div></div></div><div><div class="modal styled__Modal-a94357-0 fQRtzL"><aside class="overlay styled__Overlay-gtv01n-0 joIHPo"></aside><div radius="4" display="flex" direction="column" width="100%" height="auto" cursor="initial" order="0" class="Modal__Container-sc-13j9751-1 cbeGrw Container__ContainerStyle-sc-1iqy2ia-0 dVRtOm"><button class="fechar styled__Button-sc-6mz6kj-0 EOEkK" font-size="0.875rem" width="100%"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 30 30"><path fill="#9B9B9B" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.106 15.09L8.227 19.85l1.625 2.035 5.119-4.976 5.099 4.976 1.882-1.83-5.109-4.966 5.109-4.967-1.882-1.83-5.1 4.976-5.118-4.976-1.625 2.035 4.879 4.762zM15 30C6.716 30 0 23.284 0 15 0 6.716 6.716 0 15 0c8.284 0 15 6.716 15 15 0 8.284-6.716 15-15 15z"></path></svg></button><div class="sc-1o2smz3-1 gwBrau styled__Row-sc-13w6d15-0 gCsrNl"><div font-size="14" width="auto" class="Alert__StyledAlert-huwm74-0 cOBlGy"><div><i size="20" width="auto" height="auto" transform="initial" class="Icon__StyledIcon-t66fqd-0 ilQPJq"><svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g fill="#f8562c"><path d="M15,0 C6.72,0 0,6.72 0,15 C0,23.28 6.72,30 15,30 C23.28,30 30,23.28 30,15 C30,6.72 23.28,0 15,0 Z M16.5,22.5 L13.5,22.5 L13.5,19.5 L16.5,19.5 L16.5,22.5 Z M16.5,16.5 L13.5,16.5 L13.5,7.5 L16.5,7.5 L16.5,16.5 Z"></path></g></svg></i></div><div><p color="#222" type="p" align="left" font-family="Simplon, OiTextRegular, simplon_bpregular, sans-serif" font-weight="Regular" font-size="16" fontcolor="#222222" themecolor="dark" margin="0" padding="0" width="100%" height="auto" lineheight="1em" letter-spacing="normal" whitespace="initial" maxwidth="initial" class="Text__TextStyle-fp0yjz-0 beCits">Ocorreu um erro ao baixar o arquivo.<br>Tente novamente mais tarde.</p></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: element = null. Therefore, **NullPointerException**

Comment: Post the code that is throwing the NPE. Given your code, that shouldn't happen. An element that is enabled and displayed can't be null. Are you sure the locator is good? Maybe none of the elements are visible/enabled?

Comment: @FelipeLuz Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML and exactly which element you are trying to locate/click

Comment: I updated the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show how I would go about it, but the problem might be a problem with selenium not always returning isDisplayed() correctly depending on the element type.

```
public WebElement getFirstVisibleElement(List<WebELement> elements) {
    for (WebElement ele : elements)
        if (ele.isEnabled() && ele.isDisplayed())
            return ele;
    return null;
}
```

A more reliable method of checking if a web element is displayed is to check its dimensions (height and width).  If they are both zero, it's not displayed.

```
public WebElement getFirstVisibleElement(List<WebELement> elements) {
    for (WebElement ele : elements)
        if (ele.isEnabled() && ele.getSize().getHeight() > 0 && ele.getSize().getWidth() > 0 )
            return ele;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! In the first method the element is null, so its showing the nullpoint exception. The second method is collecting an element that is more on the bottom of the page, I don't know why

Comment: Actually, in the first method the loop doesn't return the 'ele'

Comment: You have to anticipate a null return and check it from the call to this method, otherwise, you need to handle it in some other fashion, but there are going to be scenarios where there are no visible elements in the array, so you need to plan and act accordingly in your test.  I would place a breakpoint in the code to stop on the line that tests for enabled and displayed and check the values of each element one at a time - the same with the second method.  Maybe you can elaborate more on what you're working with.

Comment: I'm doing this right now, and your code worked fine. Thank you!!